# DPDK rte_mbuf packets not freed properly

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, dpdk

### TL;DR

I am using `DPDK` to receive UDP packets at a high throughput. When I try to free `rte_mbufs` (UDP packets) using `rte_pktmbuf_free_bulk()` on a thread not running on a DPDK `lcore`, the `rte_mbuf`s are not actually freed, which leads to the inability to receive more than 4096 packets. Do I need to move all my logic onto threads running on `lcore`s, or is there something else I can do to make this work?

### Note about the DPDK setup

I am new to DPDK and inherited the initialization part of the code, which is entirely too long to include here. I am not sure which specific details about the configuration might be important or relevant, but will be happy to supplement this post if anyone has specific questions about the DPDK setup. However, I have included the main RX loop code and a description of it, below.

### Notes about the code:

- The main RX loop is contained in a method called `_receive_packets()`, which is only called using `rte_eal_remote_launch()`, which is why the arguments are passed in with a void pointer.
- `thread_arg` is a struct that I have defined to pass in all the arguments I need when calling this function with `rte_eal_remote_launch()`.
- For reasons that are not likely relevant to this question, `_receive_packets()` must be a static class method, which is why you see the strange `input_arg->ds_instance` notation. `input_arg->ds_instance` is simply a pointer to the `Data_Streamer` instance that called `_receive_packets()`.
- `input_arg->ds_instance->m_active` becomes false when it is time for the application to shut down.
- `BURST_SIZE` is 512
- `IO_Job` is a struct that I use to send the packets to another (non lcore) thread using an `rte_ring` to be processed and streamed to file. The code that dequeues the jobs calls `rte_eal_remote_launch()` on the packets and deletes any object created in `_receive_packets()`, so it may look like there is a memory leak, but there is not.
- `input_arg->ds_instance->enqueue_io_job()` is a helper function that simply enqueues a job to the `rte_ring` mentioned above.

### The code

```
void Data_Streamer::_receive_packets(void* arg) 
{
    thread_arg* input_arg = (thread_arg*) arg;

    uint16_t port_id = input_arg->port_id;
    uint16_t queue_id = input_arg->queue_id;
    long long bytes_recorded = 0;

    
    while (input_arg->ds_instance->m_active)
    {
        // If BURST_SIZE packets not ready, then do nothing this cycle
        if (rte_eth_rx_queue_count(port_id, queue_id) < BURST_SIZE) continue;
        
        // Once data is available, get packets as burst
        rte_mbuf** packets = new rte_mbuf*[BURST_SIZE];
        const uint16_t got_num_packets = rte_eth_rx_burst(port_id, queue_id, packets, BURST_SIZE);

        // Package packets into job and enqueue the job
        if (got_num_packets)
        {
            IO_Job* job = new IO_Job;
            job->byte_offset = bytes_recorded;
            job->packets = packets;
            job->num_packets = got_num_packets;

            input_arg->ds_instance->enqueue_io_job(job);
        }
    }
}
```

### Troubleshooting notes

- When I modify the code such that `rte_pktmbuf_free_bulk()` is called from `_receive_packets()` immediately after the job is enqueued, then the packets are freed as expected, however, this creates a race condition where the data in the packets might be overwritten with new packet data before it can be processed on the non `lcore` thread.
- I tried to further modify the code such that the packets are cached within `_receive_packets()` until the process running on the non `lcore` thread sends a notification that it is done using the data, upon which the packets are freed in `_receive_packets()`. In this case the behavior is similar to when the packets are freed in the non `lcore` thread -- the packets are not freed. (As if just looking at the data in the non `lcore` thread prevents it from being freed properly, even when freed from the `lcore` thread.)
- If I repeat the above attempt, but instead extract the address of the buffer I actually care to read from using `rte_pktmbuf_mtod()` such that I never send pointers to the packets objects to the non `lcore` thread, it still does not free the `rte_mbuf`s properly.

Comment: Using `rte_pktmbuf_free_bulk()` in all threads which the packet data is accessed -kind of- fixed the problem. I can now receive more than 4096 packets. However, the data in every packet after packet 4096 is not as expected. It seems the `mbuf`s have been freed to be used again, but maybe there is some garbage data in those `mbuf`s. Does anyone know what else I might need to do to successfully reuse a freed `mbuf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to execute ALL code that makes use of `mbuf`s on DPDK lcore threads. There is no need to free the packets with `rte_pktmbuf_free()` on all threads that use the packets, as I had previously suggested in my comments. If all threads are running on DPDK lcores, then only a single call to `rte_pktmbuf_free()` is required.

I thought I could get away with reading data from the mbufs in threads not running on DPDK lcores, but apparently even read operations are only thread safe if the reads are performed on threads running on DPDK lcores.